# Location of error.log File on Windows System

Tags: install4j

How do I change the location of the "error.log" file that by default gets placed in the same folder as the install exe when performing a quiet (-q) unattended install?

Answer (score 0):

Since install4j, there the installer and custom installer applications have a "Log file for stderr" property. By default, it is set to `${compiler:sys.mediaFileName}_error.log`.